# Is there a order/sequence pipes getting applied with angular?

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I came across this issue today, i am filtering the items which are ACTIVE and displaying only the first 2 items after filtered, here is the code i had

```
<div *ngFor="let l of listings | slice:0:2 | filterByStatus:'ACTIVE'  ">
  <listing-item [listing]="l"></listing-item>
</div>
```

It did not work, but when i replace the order of pipe, its working properly.

```
<div *ngFor="let l of listings | filterByStatus:'ACTIVE' | slice:0:2   ">
  <listing-item [listing]="l"></listing-item>
</div>
```

is this an expected behaviour or we can use it in any order?

Comment: They do have an order, it's like piping stuff on the shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.
In the first example
`slice` is applied first and `filterByStatus` to the result of `slice`,
in the 2nd exapmle the order is the other way around.

You can also use parens to influence evaluation order like

```
(someobservable | async).items | slice:0:2
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipes are executed in left-to-right order, so the order is important.

In your example, only the second version makes sense. You want to filter first, then select the first two of what remains, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

While chaining the Pipes the sequence does matter. So in first case, slice will run first and will return the results to the next pipe to process.